# Get user list in my keycloak (18.0) realm with client roles

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to get the user list within the *Client Roles* of my realm via REST API.
I'm using an admin user in my realm and I assigned him view-users (in *Role Mappings - Client Roles -> realm-management -> view-users*).

Here my results of GET calls:

1. get user (ok)
   /admin/realms/my-realms/users
2. get role (ok)
   /admin/realms/my-realms/roles
3. get client role (**KO**)
   /admin/realms/my-realms/clients/my-client-id/roles

The third call doesn't work with **Could not find client** error.
I tried also to add *view-clients* like view-users in the *realm-management*.

I'm interested to get all users that have got this *Client Roles* role, and I replace users at the end of call 3 instead of roles, and I have an *unknown_error* error.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin of my-realms needs to `view-clients` role.
It can see the client's role.

[image]

[image]

[image]